# Собственный тип класса на основе примитивного типа

Tags: java, типы-данных

> В языке `jаvа` определены восемь примитивных типов данных: `byte` , `short` , `int` , `long`, `char`, `float`, `double` и `boolean`. Примитивные типы называют также простыми, и [в данной книге](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/) употребляются оба эти термина. Примитивные типы
>   можно разделить на следующие четыре группы.
>
> - Целые числа. Эта группа включает в себя типы данных `byte` , `short` , `int`
>     и `long`, представляющие целые числа со знаком.
> - Числа с плавающей точкой. Эта группа включает в себя типы данных `flоаt`
>     и `double` , представляющие числа с точностью до определенного знака после
>     десятичной точки.
> - Символы. Эта группа включает в себя тип данных `char` , представляющий
>     символы, например буквы и цифры, из определенного набора.
> - Логические значения. Эта группа включает в себя тип данных `boolean`,
>     специально предназначенный для представления логических истинных
>     и ложных значений.
>
> Эти типы данных можно использовать непосредственно **или для создания собственных
>   типов классов**. Таким образом, они служат основанием для всех других
>   типов данных, которые могут быть созданы.

Использование "непосредственно" мне понятно, всюду и постоянно. А что за "**собственные типы классов**"? На основе примитивных? Вроде нельзя. В обычном создании класса эти типы включаются непосредственно по необходимости, зачем тогда "**или**"?

**UPD**
Вопрос решен, ошибочка в русском переводе книги, спасибо @Regent

Comment: Надо полагать, в "You can use these types as-is, or to construct arrays or your own class types. Thus, they
form the basis for all other types of data that you can create." под использованием "as-is" подразумевается использование примитивов как локальных переменных в методах, а под "construct your own class types" - как полей созданных классов. Занятно что в русском варианте куда-то пропало "construct arrays".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственные типы (классы) - ваши типы (классы). Которые вы создадите при помощи `class <имя класса> {}`. В данном случае класс и тип синонимы.

Классы это составные типы. Они состоят из примитивов и/или других классов. Примитивы не составные.